# Saving Large XML file with PUGIXML repeatedly takes a lot of time

Tags: c++, pugixml

I have a 65Mb XML file that I am loading and modifying with PUGIXML. Problem is that I need to keep it updated and saved to disk so that other files can access. I don't want to implement a database, so is there a way for me to make modifications, and just save those few modifications, instead of dumping the entire document to file? I notice about a 3-4 second delay each time I save the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question. But anyway, let me answer.
pugixml has a mode of saving data via a `write` interface. This effectively solves the problem of having to dump the entire file because you can chunk the data into smaller pieces and write to a file.

From the [documentation](http://pugixml.org/docs/manual.html#saving.writer):

> This is a simple interface with a single function, which is called
>   several times during output process with chunks of document data as
>   input:
>
> ```
> class xml_writer
> {
> public:
>     virtual void write(const void* data, size_t size) = 0;
> };
>
> void xml_document::save(xml_writer& writer, const char_t* indent = "\t",
>                         unsigned int flags = format_default,
>                         xml_encoding encoding = encoding_auto) const;
> ```
>
> ...
>
> write function is called with relatively large blocks (size is usually
>   several kilobytes, except for the last block that may be small), so
>   there is often no need for additional buffering in the implementation.

And there's one more way to solve this problem: by saving one subtree at a time. Again, from the [documentation](http://pugixml.org/docs/manual.html#saving.subtree):

> To save a single subtree, the following functions are provided:

```
void xml_node::print(std::ostream& os, const char_t* indent = "\t", unsigned int flags = format_default, xml_encoding encoding = encoding_auto, unsigned int depth = 0) const;
void xml_node::print(std::wostream& os, const char_t* indent = "\t", unsigned int flags = format_default, unsigned int depth = 0) const;
void xml_node::print(xml_writer& writer, const char_t* indent = "\t", unsigned int flags = format_default, xml_encoding encoding = encoding_auto, unsigned int depth = 0) const;
```

> These functions have the same arguments with the same meaning as the
>   corresponding xml_document::save functions, and allow you to save the
>   subtree to either a C++ IOstream or to any object that implements
>   xml_writer interface.